# How do break and continue loops work in python?

Tags: python

input: 17

```
  stop = int(input())
    result = 0
    for a in range(5):
        for b in range(3):
            result += a + b
        print(result)
        if result > stop:
            break
```

Can someone please explain to me how this code yields:
3
9
18

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how those numbers are computed... any help is appreciated!

Comment: The 1 million dollars question:  what's the input?

Comment: input is 17 - sorry forgot to add that

Comment: i know the result is 3 9 18.... i just don't get why those numbers are the result..

Answer (score 1):

The best I can explain is like this:

```
stop = int(input("Input a stop value:"))
print(f"stop value is: {stop}")
result = 0
for a in range(5):
    for b in range(3):
        print(f"adding: a{a} + b{b}")
        result += a + b
        print(f"result is now: {result}")
    if result > stop:
        print(f"result {result} is superior to {stop}, break")
        break

print(f"\nFinal result is {result}")
```

---

```
Input a stop value: 17
stop value is: 17
adding: a0 + b0
result is now: 0
adding: a0 + b1
result is now: 1
adding: a0 + b2
result is now: 3
adding: a1 + b0
result is now: 4
adding: a1 + b1
result is now: 6
adding: a1 + b2
result is now: 9
adding: a2 + b0
result is now: 11
adding: a2 + b1
result is now: 14
adding: a2 + b2
result is now: 18
result 18 is superior to 17, break

Final result is 18
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/b628778da9)

Comment: alright I understand all the a0 + b0 stuff, but why doesn't it print out all those numbers (0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 18) and instead only 3, 9, 18 ?

Comment: I think the solution provided above is printing all the numbers (0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 18) primarily because the print is inside the second for loop. As for your print  statement @draeway is outside the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop adds `a` 3 times to result and all values of `b` (0, 1, and 2). This means that every time the loop runs, result += 3*a + 3. Then, the outer loop prints this value. At 0 initially, after the first increment with a=0, this is 3 (adds 3*0+3) after the second increment 9 (adds 3*1+3=6) and the third 18 (adds 3*2+3=9). Each round it also checks if the result is larger than the value at which to stop and calls the break keyword. In Python, this ends the execution of a loop immediately, so the program exits the outer loop and completes the program. `continue`, as you asked about in the title skips the remaining code in the loop after the statement.